# Why is the maximum height of a mountain approximately 10 kms?

Tags: classical-mechanics

from my textbook

> A mountain base is not under uniform compression and this provides some shearing stress to the rocks under which they can **flow**.
>
> **The stress due to all the material on the top should be less than the critical shearing stress at which the rocks flow**
>    At the bottom of the mountain of heigh h, the force per unit area due to the weight of the montain is h x density x g. The material at the bottom experiences this force in the vertical direction, and the sides of the mountain are free. Therefore theis is not a case of pressure or bulk compression.

**There is a shear component approximately h x density x g**

My questions are

(i)Why is the shear component ( shearing stress) equal to hx density of the rock 
   x g. How is a vertical force like pressure even related to a tangential force like shearing stess

(ii)What's critical stress ? Why is the stress due to all the material on top less that that of the base stress.

(iii) The stress on top is not shearing stess, it's the weight of the material in unit area or pressure, am i correct?

(iV) could you provide a simple explanation of the passage, I understand that for mountain the base is in kinda molten state.

Comment: Note that while Everest is 29,000 ft (on Earth), Mons Olympus is 29,000 m (on Mars), but its in $3 \over 8$g gravity.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Mohr's circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohr%27s_circle) technique of transforming normal stresses into shear stresses? The passage is describing an order-of-magnitude approximation of the shear stress as transformed from the normal stress arising from the mountain's weight. It's not an exact calculation.

Comment: nope i'm not familiar withMohr's circle